# Dataflow read from Bigquery with repeated field

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to read Bigquery, basically GA data into dataflow, which is with repeated field.

Is it possible to read repeated field into dataflow?

Comment: BigQuery will flatten your data when you read form repearted field. So I don't see any issue there. Can you please edit your post with sample data you are trying to read and how you want to process it using Dataflow?

Comment: Just try it and see what happens ;-)

Comment: I feel a good hint. OMG!